# I am using webpack5 with Angular13.I am facing issue in getting images from assets folder. The images are not loading from right path inside packs

Tags: angular, image, webpack-5, file-loader

The images which is by default loaded is "**http://localhost:3000/packs/467c3a4a10eff4d07d15.jpg**" but it should load from "**http://localhost:3000/packs/media/images/cm_logo12345.jpg**".I have used file-loader also but nothing is working. Any help would be appreciable.

I tried using file-loader but still the image is loading from packs but i want it from 'packs/media/images/abc.png'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.